# LINUX cp -r with attributes (sepecially icon)

Tags: linux-mint, cp, desktop-icons

LINUX Mint 20.04 I need this for a script that already has worked in UBUNTU but doesn't anymore in Mint.

My problem: I have a directory for which I have changed the icon by simply right-clicking on it in nemo --> properties --> click on the icon --> select a new icon.

If I copy this directory with nemo to another place, it keeps its appearance. (the icon)

But when I copy this directory with the console `cp -r` ... it looses its appearance. (looks like an normal directory)

My question: What parameter do I need to add, to `cp -r` to copy the properties to the new directory like if I had copied it with nemo?

I've already tried:

```
cp -ra
cp -ra -attributes-only
cp -rp
```

But all these did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To imitate Nemo you would need to use `gio copy`. Unfortunately it doesn't have `-r`, so you'll need to figure that out separately.

Nautilus, Nemo, and Thunar store such properties in a separate metadata database, not directly as attributes on the file itself. You can verify the absence of xattrs using `getfattr -d ~/Foo`, and you can see all properties visible to GNOME apps – including xattrs as well as the custom metadata stored by GVfs – using `gio info ~/Foo`.

This means that you must use tools that use GLib/GVfs functions to copy the file; anything else will not know how to copy GVfs-level metadata. (I assume KDE might have a similar problem; it has `kio cp`.)

For now, since the `gio` tool doesn't support copying recursively, you will instead need to find the specific metadata item in `gio info` for the old folder, then manually set it on the new folder with `gio set` (after copying the folder in whatever way you prefer).

Comment: Perfect answer. Didn't know that.